# Can the additional time it takes to execute the first instance of a query be eliminated in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

Whatever steps I take, the first example of any query I make in neo4j *always* takes longer than any subsequent execution of the same query. So I guess something other than the store is being cached.

- I'm using the latest **community** container image for 3.5 (`3.5.20` at the time of writing)
- I have **plenty of memory** to cache absolutely everything if I want to
- I'm **using well documented warm-up strategies** in order to (allegedly) prime the page cache

### The database details...

I run `CALL apoc.monitor.store();` and it tells me the size of each *store*: -

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| logSize | stringStoreSize | arrayStoreSize | relStoreSize | propStoreSize | totalStoreSize | nodeStoreSize |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1224    | 148165607424    | 3016515584     | 26391839040  | 42701007672   | 241318778285   | 2430128610    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I run `CALL apoc.warmup.run(true, true, true);` (before running any queries). It takes about 15 minutes and displays a summary of what it's done. The text it outputs is not easily parsed in its raw form so I've summarised salient parts of it below. Basically it tells me the number of pages loaded for each store, and these are: -

```
nodePages           296,719
relPages          3,234,294
relGroupPages         4,580
propPages         5,233,608
stringPropPages  18,086,620
arrayPropPages      368,225
indexPages        2,235,227
---
Total            29,459,273
```

- With a page size of 8,192 bytes per page that's approximately **225GiB of pages** for the displayed stores
- I have enough physical memory and I have already set `NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size` to **250G**
- I set `NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_initial__size` and `NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size` to **8G**

So (allegedly) the page cache is "warm" and I have enough physical memory.

### Query timings...

I run my query, which returns 1,813 records, and I execute the same query several times in order to illustrate the issue. I see the following (typical) timings: -

```
1.  1,821 mS
2.     75 mS
3.     60 mS
4.     51 mS
5.     48 mS
6.     42 mS
7.     38 mS
8.     36 mS
9.     36 mS
```

The actual values are dependent on the query but the first execution of *every* query is *always* significantly longer than the second.

> **ADDENDUM (16/Jul)**.
> Just to be clear, using `apoc.warmup.run` does help.
> If I don't use it, the first query is much longer still.
> Having just restarted the DB (without a warm-up) the first query
> took **7,829mS**. The 2nd was **116mS**, the third **66mS**
>
> So, warm-up or not, the first query is *always* longer.

### Question...

- What's going on?
- Can I do anything more to reduce the initial query time?

  - *Oh, and using the query as the warm up is not the answer - I don't know what queries will be used*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `apoc.warmup.run` does not speed up your initial query, but you could just try using an initial query invocation as your "warmup" instead.

Comment: Agreed. Sadly, in the general case, I don't now in advance what query will be executed. But it is something we're considering ... i.e. as part of the container start-up we: a) warm-up the cache then b) run a series of "representative" queries. But - we ask ourselves "what's the point of the warm-up if you have to run the query anyway?"  Clearly there's something else neo4j is caching that can't be done in advance.

Comment: I should make it clear that `apoc.warmup.run` *does* speed up the initial query. If you *don't* use it then the initial query is even longer. So, yes, it does help but (use it or not) the initial query is always longer. So the warmup is helping but clearly there's more stuff that neo4j keeps after the query that's not being cached by the warmup.

Comment: I've added an **ADDENDUM** to the original post. If I don't warm-up the cache at all then my first query is 4 times longer again (about 8 seconds instead of about 2 seconds). But the first query (warm-up or not) is always longer.